# Can i run analysis with sonarlint and see the same on sonarqube server without involving sonar scanner at all

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I have installed Sonar Scanner and Sonar Qube and i am running code analysis with Sonar Scanner and i can see the results on Sonar Qube server in bowser. Also,I have SonarLint added in my VS2015 and i am using connected mode with my sonar qube server. And i run analysis with sonar lint also locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sonar Scanner is a program that connects to a SonarQube server, downloads analyzers and active rules, runs the analyzers locally on your source code, and finally pushes the analysis results to SonarQube, so that you can manage the quality of your source code on SonarQube.

SonarLint is designed to analyze files as you work on them in your IDE (VS2015 in your case). It does not produce analysis reports and does not push them to SonarQube server. Not even in connected mode. The purpose of connected mode is to use the same analyzers and same rules as configured on SonarQube. Pushing analysis reports to the server is out of the scope of SonarLint.

In short, if you want to see analysis results on SonarQube and manage the quality of your software, you cannot skip the Sonar Scanner.